# Collision event function not running

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection

I am recreating flappy bird as a quick project to help me understand the ins and outs of unity. However I have hit a road block. When the bird collides with the pipe or ground it is not kicking off the `void onCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D target)`

The Bird, the pole, and the ground are not triggers. They are all tagged correctly. Here is my code for the onCollisionEnter2D function.

```
    void onCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D target)
{
    Debug.Log("Entered 2D Collision");

    if (target.gameObject.tag == "Ground" || target.gameObject.tag == "Pipe")
    {
        if (isAlive)
        {
            isAlive = false;
            anim.SetTrigger("Bird Died:");
            audioSource.PlayOneShot(deadClip);
        }
    }
}
```

Even my debuging code is not being reached. So I am stuck as to why this function isn't being executed when the bird collides with the pole or ground. They both all have 2D collision boxes on them.

Comment: The number of people having the **exact** same problem is incalculable...

Answer (score 2):

It's `OnCollisionEnter2D`, not `onCollisionEnter2D`. See the [docs here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnCollisionEnter2D.html).

Comment: Yes this is it. I was staring at it forever. Let this be a lesson to me to check for capitalization in the function. <3